# What is more efficient(fastest) way of continuously sorting 10000 records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Im continuously reading updated 3 times a second price.csv, sort by volume using df.nlargest or df.sort_values, which method is faster??

```
#Read stock price from price.csv, sort by volume, print Highest stock volume.
import pandas as pd
while 1==1:    
    try:
        df=pd.read_csv ("R:/price.csv").dropna()
        #df=df.nlargest(1,'volume')                                #first method
        #df.sort_values('volume',ascending=False,inplace=True)     #second method   
        print ("\t",df.iloc[0,0],df.iloc[0,1] )  
    except:
        pass
del df
```

Sample output:

```
 SNDL 79416563.0 
 SNDL 79552154.0 
 ITUB 20537823.0 
 PCG 24423451.0 
 EDU 104113726.0 
 TSM 5074870.0 
 EDU 105639190.0 
 ABEV 30110259.0 
 CEI 10292901.0 
 PCG 24739218.0 
 SWN 19374652.0
```

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: The faster is to avoid to open/read/close your file 3 times per second... Find another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know for sure.

But, my fancy Computer Science degree tells me that sorting in order to "find the max value" is not the way to go.  The computational complexity of sorting is, at best, O(N) and most often is closer to O(N*log(N)).  Whereas finding the maximum (or minimum) of an unsorted list is always O(N).

So, what does that mean?  Don't sort the file to find the max value, search for it.  That tells me that `df.nlargest(1,'volume')` (the first method) is most likely going to be what you want to be using, from a theoretical point of view.